# Type mismatch: cannot convert from integer to boolean

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

```
public boolean clearSelection() {
    int i = 0;
    if (!this.m_SelectedComps.isEmpty()) {
        i = 1;
        Iterator localIterator = this.m_SelectedComps.iterator();
        while (localIterator.hasNext())
            ((AnnotComponent) localIterator.next()).remove();
        this.m_SelectedComps.clear();
    }

    return i;
}
```

How to convert the integer to boolean?

Comment: Java is not like C++.In C++ 0 is false and other integers are true, in Java integer can't be used as boolean.

Comment: What is the purpose of the integer? There is no obvious reason to use anything else than boolean for your example. 

@shift66 That feature isn't C++ specific. It's a general rule. I can't remeber another language beside JAVA which can't convert int to bool.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try using this return

```
return i == 1;
```

or just use a boolean to start (with a better name):

```
 public boolean clearSelection()
  {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (!this.m_SelectedComps.isEmpty())
    {
      flag = true;
      Iterator localIterator = this.m_SelectedComps.iterator();
      while (localIterator.hasNext())
        ((AnnotComponent)localIterator.next()).remove();
      this.m_SelectedComps.clear();
    }
    return flag;
  }
```

It continues to mystify me why people use `i` -- a horrible variable name.  Looks like `1` and does not convey any meaning.

Comment: Concerning `i`: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things" -- Phil Karlton

Comment: @JanDvorak - Thank you for that quote.  As a corollary : The first step in naming things well is not using `i`.

Comment: @Hogan Not sure which font you're using, it sure don't look like a `1` in my IDE

Comment: `i` comes from Fortran.

Comment: IMO `i` comes from "iterate", "iterator"

Comment: @PetkoPetkov - lol, `i` was being used **WAY** before the term iterator was in the vernacular.

Comment: Should we define ´true´ as 1 or everything that is not 0?

Comment: @anustart - I'm not sure what you are asking -- if you are commenting on the statement `return i == 1;` then it has nothing to do with "defining true", since it is code as relates to the question which only assigns `1` or `0` to the integer so using `i > 0` would make the code less clear, in my opinion.  If this isn't your point then please explain.

Comment: For instance, if `i = 42`, `i == 1` is false, while `i != 0` is true. I thought the rules were "Zero is false, everything else is true", but it's probably just for C++.

Comment: @anustart - Yes that "rule" was in the C standard originally and carried over to other languages but not Java.  Which is why this question was asked.  Java can't convert an integer to a boolean.  To do that conversion using C standards does not makes sense.  What makes sense is to look at the code you are writing (the original question in this case) and write code that is **clear in the context of the function it is in**.  This is why I think Pryank's answer (as an example) is not so good.  He is ignoring the context.

Comment: imagine if somebody used l. thats small case L as a variable name. as far as i, its acceptable to me if its an iterator and is being incremented or decremented.

Comment: I think `i` is from "integer".

Comment: Yes, my comment is not related to the code, but to your question ("why people use `i`?")

Comment: Again, I was simply answering your question about why *people* use `i`, if we say "people", we talk about something general, different persons writing different codes using same variable name `i`, some of them for integers, and some of them for non integers.

Comment: @stramin -- people do things for many reasons, sometimes smart, sometimes not.  My point is that all those reasons for using `i` as a variable are bad.  There are good reasons to not use `i` as a variable name and there are no good reasons to do so.  Many people still do it.  StackOverflow is a place for us all to improve our coding skills.  This is a simple way to do so -- I **strongly** advocate not using `i`.  I've yet to see a good reason to use it.  If more people took my position we could start to see new programmers not do it just because they see others doing it on this site.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I also think all those reasons are bad, I use `f` as variable for `for`, when I simply want to repeat something 3 times `for(f=0;f<3;f++)` because there is not really any meaning, whatever, I agree it is a bad practice. I think the most people use `i` because many teachers teach this way (also `c` for chars, `f` for floats, and even `array` for arrays)

Answer (score 17):

May be you can just modify your return statement without much change to code as below:

```
return i > 0 ? true : false ;
```

Comment: Nice but what if the int equal to 0! 
It won't work even if you use >= because when int is null this line of code will return true always.

Comment: The ternary operator is redundant. It's enough to write `return i > 0;`.

Answer (score 16):

I know this thread is old but wanted add some code that helped me and might help others searching this...

You could use org.apache.commons.lang api to convert an int to boolean using the BooleanUtils class:

```
BooleanUtils.toBoolean(int value)
```

"Converts an int to a boolean using the convention that zero is false." (Javadocs)

---

Here are the Maven & Gradle dependencies, just make sure you check you're using the latest version on the link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle Dependency:

```
'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

Comment: It's things like this that give Java a bad name. Why would anyone use this instead of just `value != 0`? (Which results in a boolean using the convention that zero is false)

Comment: @SalmanvonAbbas I'm not sure I follow. In C, zero is false and non-zero is true. This is pretty widely accepted.

Comment: @SalmanvonAbbas There are many valid reason for Java is problematic, but this is just an util function. I see all fine here.

Comment: Here's a good use case: I have used this lib to parse a text config value into boolean, for flexibility. These would all return true: 'true', 'on', 'y', 't' , 'yes', 'TrUe'. I wouldn't ADD the lib to parse 1 and 0. But would definitely use it if it's already in my project.

Answer (score 5):

Convert int to boolean:

```
return i > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare i as a boolean:

```
public boolean clearSelection()
{
    boolean i = false;
    if (!this.m_SelectedComps.isEmpty())
    {
        i = true;
        Iterator localIterator = this.m_SelectedComps.iterator();
        while (localIterator.hasNext())
          ((AnnotComponent)localIterator.next()).remove();
        this.m_SelectedComps.clear();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean clearSelection(){
    int i = 0;
    if (!this.m_SelectedComps.isEmpty())
    {
        i = 1;
        Iterator localIterator = this.m_SelectedComps.iterator();
        while (localIterator.hasNext())
            ((AnnotComponent)localIterator.next()).remove();
        this.m_SelectedComps.clear();
     }
     return (i!=0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't type cast between integer and boolean in Java but you could use the following technique which I use oftenly:

To convert boolean into integer:

```
int i;
return i != 0;
```

To convert integer into boolean:

```
boolean b;
return b ? 1 : 0;
```