# cannot convert from int to boolean. Java Error (New Case)

Tags: java, int, boolean

I'm working in `TicTacToe` gui program in java. I have created a class `PlayerTurn`. In order to check for the player turn I used `player = (player%2) ? 1 : 2;` in java. I used in a C++ project and it worked fine but in Java I get error **Type Mismatch : Cannot convert from int to boolean** 
I have declared player as an *int.*

Comment: What is the type of the result of `(player%2)`? What type does the first operand of `?:` have to be?

Comment: Dupe: [Type mismatch: cannot convert from integer to boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9271885/572670) - though I don't want to close it on my own opinion...

Comment: @MirwiseKhan : Okay please see my updated answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ternary operator:

```
    result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

`testCondition` has to be a `boolean` value. If `testCondition` evaluates to `true`, then `result = value1`. Else, `result = value2` .

Therefore, `player = (player%2) ? 1 : 2` doesn't work.(**Type Mismatch : Cannot convert from int to boolean**) `(player%2)` is an int, not a boolean value. Change it to:

```
player = (player%2 == 1) ? 1 : 2
```

Translates to:

```
Is player%2 == 1?
   Yes?  Then player = 1
   No?   Then player = 2
```

Here's a good example:

```
min_Val = a < b ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the result of the modulo operation to something, since the condition in a ternary expression has to be a `boolean`. I am guessing you want to compare with `1`:

```
player = (player%2 == 1) ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: Most likely he's after `!= 0`, because in many C-like languages, 0 stands for `false`.

Comment: @amit: Yes, I realized that too.