# How to resolve "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean" java error?

Tags: java

I am working on the book "Introduction to java programming" and when I try to run one of the examples on the book I got an error which I couldn't resolve.
The code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubtractionQuizLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 5;

        int correctCount = 0;

        int count = 0;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String output = " ";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {
            int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

            if (number1 < number2){
                int temp = number1;
                number1 = number2;
                number2 = temp;
            }

            System.out.println("What is " + number1 + " minus " + number2 + "?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            if(number1 - number2 == answer) {
                System.out.println("You are correct");
                correctCount++;

            }else {
                System.out.println("Your answer is wrong.\n" + number1 + "-" + number2 + "=" + (number1 - number2));
            }

                count++;
                output += "\n" + number1 + "–" + number2 + "=" + answer + ((number1 – number2 == answer) ? " correct": " wrong");
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long testTime = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Correct count is " + correctCount + "\nTest  time is " + testTime / 1000 + "seconds\n" + output);

        }
    }

}
```

And the error message is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", invalid AssignmentOperator
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int

    at SubtractionQuizLoop.main(SubtractionQuizLoop.java:41)
```

when I try to update the output variable. Casting `(number1 – number2 == answer)` to `int` and `boolean` do not resolve the error as well. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type mismatch: cannot convert from integer to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271885/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-integer-to-boolean)

Comment: You seem to have used an en-dash instead of a minus sign in that expression, otherwise your code should work.

Comment: Additionally, you have too many closing braces - probably because the code starting `count++;` is incorrectly indented.

Comment: @Sweeper I used hyphen instead of minus sign and also included additional brace at the end that is not required.

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw that too. Now problem fixed thanks.

Comment: Remove one curly brace from bottom.

Comment: @CodeRider I just did and resolved it.

Comment: I would suggest deleting this question at this point, as it was basically just a typo.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: "These are compilation errors, before executing you should resolve the errors indicated by the compiler." The question is precisely about *how* to resolve the error indicated by the compiler. (And it isn't a terribly helpful error message in this particular case.)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I completely agree it's best to fix the compilation error before trying to run the code, and saying *that* part would have been useful. (I hadn't actually noticed that the OP had tried to run the code.) But I found your comment dismissive, as if it were an obvious issue based on the error message - and while you didn't write the error message, your comment did seem to assume that just reading the error message would make it obvious what was wrong, when it really didn't.